# Refreshing PubSubHubbub subscription for Youtube API in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, youtube-data-api

I managed to subscribe to a Youtube Feed through https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe on a web browser, I've been trying to refresh my subscription to PubSubHubbub through Fetch on NodeJS, the code I used is below

```
const details = {
  'hub.mode': 'subscribe',
  'hub.topic': 'https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=${process.env.ID}',
  'hub.callback': process.env.callback,
  'hub.secret': process.env.secret
};
const endpoint = 'http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe'

var formBody = [];
for (const property in details) {
  const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
  const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
  formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}

formBody = formBody.join("&");
const result = await fetch(endpoint, { method: "POST", body: formBody, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

console.log(result.status, await result.text())
```

Expected:
Status 204

Actual:
Status 400, content: "Invalid value for hub.mode:"

I expected at least for the content to tell me what the invalid value was, however it ended up being blank, it appears to me that it did not manage to read the POSTed content at all. I'm looking for ways to improve my code so that I don't encounter this problem.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are using [google cloud PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) or not, since your question includes the google-cloud-pubsub tag?

Comment: Oh dear, sorry removed the tag, I thought it was the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that I was supposed to specify in the content type header that `charset=UTF-8`. I'm not particularly well-versed in sending requests as of yet so this is definitely an eye-opener for me. After adding it in the server responds with 204 as expected and so I'll close my question.

A workout that I tried while trying to fix this was to import the `exec()` function from child_process module to run cURL and post the request instead. However I would recommend to stick to one language to make things more readable and using `exec()` runs commands directly from the shell which may have undesirable effects.